# Smoke in evee final render is missing

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, fire

I have a smoke set up and when I render in evee all I have is the plane. I have read I need to turn volumetrics on but the volumetrics check box is missing, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: That checkbox only exists in older versions. Do you have smoke material for the domain?

Comment: Does this mean volumetrics is turned on by default?

Comment: Yes, it's always on.